# Why doesn't my ArrayList print out the output desired in Java?

Tags: java, testing, arraylist, methods, call

Pretty new user here, we are learning about methods in Java and are trying to test them using an ArrayList but it is not giving the desired output.

Here are the two methods that I created:

```
// initialize the ArrayList declared in the class block and add some test data to it
private static void addTestData()
{
    listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfNumbers.add(23);
    listOfNumbers.add(34);
    listOfNumbers.add(45);
    listOfNumbers.add(56);

}

// returns a true or a false value indicating if a number provided to it is present in an ArrayList
private static boolean listContains(int param1)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for (int x: listOfNumbers)
    {
        if (param1 == x) 
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return found;
}
```

And my goal is to test in the main method if "4" and "56" are a part of the ArrayList, so here is my code for that:

```
    boolean numberFound = false;
    addTestData();
    System.out.println("*** Testing ArrayList Search ***");
    System.out.println("I am going to test if the number 4 is in the ArrayList.");
    listContains(4);
    numberFound = false;
    
    if (numberFound = true)
        System.out.println("The number 4 was found.");
    else 
        System.out.println("The number 4 was not found.");
    
    
    System.out.println("");
    numberFound = false;
    addTestData();
    System.out.println("I am going to test if the number 56 is in the ArrayList");
    listContains(56);
    
    if (numberFound = true)
        System.out.println("The number 56 was found.");
    else 
        System.out.println("The number 56 was not found.");
```

My output tells me that 4 is a part of the ArrayList, when it is not, in fact. Any idea what to do?

[Directions for main method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bCq5.png)

[Directions for my method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdDc2.png)

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUkCV.png)

Comment: `if (numberFound = true)`, is it typo? Do you mean `==`?

Comment: This is a good use of a `HashSet`; `ArrayList` is going to have `O(n)`. `else break` breaks out of your loop, just remove it.

Comment: The code you wrote makes no sense at all. If you are starting out with programming, (which you obviously are,) *follow a tutorial*. I would also suggest to learn an easy language like Python first, before you start with Java.

Comment: Your assignment in `if (numberFound = true)` is definitely incorrect. as pointed out above. Second, you aren't capturing the return value of `listContains(int)` in a variable, so it won't impact the `numberFound` variable *at all*.
Third, your function `listContains(int)` will terminate if the first element of the list is not equivalent to `param1` supplied because you `break` if the condition isn't true. You actually want `else continue` or no `else`-block at all.

Comment: Note that you should not use `==` with booleans for just this reason. It's already a boolean; just say `if (numberFound)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are assigning rather than comparing `if (numberFound = true)`. It should be `if (numberFound == true)`, or rather simply `if (numberFound)`.
2. Your function `listContains()` returns a boolean whicih you need to assign to `numberFound`.

```
numberFound = listContains(4);
```

Or you can straight up use it in `if` condition,

```
if(listContains(4)) { }
```

3. Your function `listContains()` has issue. It should return `true` if found and `false` if not after iterating over all elements, which you are not. Right on 1st iteration, if comparison is `false`, you are breaking the loop, which return `false`

```
for (int x: listOfNumbers)
{
    if (param1 == x) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

if according to your class instruction

```
boolean found = false;
for (int x: listOfNumbers)
{
    if (param1 == x) 
    {
        found = true;
        break; // with this you can skip remaining unnecessary iteration
    }
}
return found;
```

Comment: This is an example of [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation); if the value is `true`, it will not evaluate unneeded terms.

Comment: Pretty good, but comparison should not normally be used with booleans. Not `(numberFound == true)`, just `(numberFound)`.

Comment: Thank you!! In my method, I still kept "boolean found = false;" and I returned "found" at the end according to our class instructions, but it still worked. I was mainly confused about the "listContains" and what to assign it to.

Comment: @ryanmonty42 that is fine as well, what you need to do is, you need to add `break` in `if (param1 == x){ found = true; break;}`.